# How to force paint after setting Enabled = false in a C# windows usercontrol, not WPF?

Tags: c#, winforms

How to force paint after setting Enabled = false in a C# windows usercontrol ?

Comment: Instead of saying "not WPF" use a WinForms tag (or ASP.NET, Silverlight?)  C# does not have UserControls

Comment: Changing the Enabled property already forces a repaint.  Maybe you need to call Update() if other code runs after it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `EnabledChange` event for the UserControl..

```
private void userControl_EnabledChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (! Enabled)
        Invalidate(); // ask the control to redraw itself
}
```

Note: put this code inside the userControl class, not in the form.
Good luck!

Comment: So before saying "Not WPF" Praveen, go check if there is a Winforms equivalent of what can be done in WPF. This answer is the same as the earlier one about WPF.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using winforms:

```
myControl.Invalidate();
myControl.Update();
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're talking about WPF `UserControl`s, you can just subscribe to the `IsEnabledChanged` event of your control and call `InvalidateVisual()` in the event handler.

Comment: InvalidateVisual() is not the right way to trigger repaint of WPF controls. It's very expensive, and triggers a full layout of the UI. The right way to do this is to create a DrawingGroup, place it in the visual-graph during OnRender, and then update it whenever you want later.